# combobox in usercontrol not fill - WPF & mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Good day, I'm new to WPF with MVVM, the problem in general is when filling a combox, but I'll give you some context:

I have a user control that contains different controls, including a combobox which I try to fill from the modelview but I am not successful. The user control is invoked from a main window in a few words the flow would be something like this

mainview.xaml->usercontrol.xaml->usercontrolmodelview.cs

this is where I define the source of the combobox that is inside the user control (usercontro.xaml):

```
     <ComboBox x:Name="cbConcept" Width="150" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Concepts}" DisplayMemberPath="textConcept" />
```

in this it is in usercontrolmodelview.cs linked to my user control, I define a list called Concepts that I fill it through a service (the service if it returns information and fills the list).

```
        private IEnumerable<Concept> _concepts;
        public IEnumerable<Concept> Concepts { get => _concepts; set { _concepts = value; } }

        public usercontrolmodelview()
        {
            AddItemCommand = new ViewModelCommand(ExecuteAddCommand, ValidateAddCommand);
            _api = new Api();
            _memCache = new MemCache();
            _ = LoadCatalogs();
        }
        private async Task LoadCatalogs()
        {
            _concepts = _memCache.GetCache<IEnumerable<Concept>>(KeysCache.CompanyCache);
            if (_concepts == null)
            {
                _companys = await _api.GetConcept();
                _memCache.SaveCache(_concepts, KeysCache.CompanyCache);
            }
        }
```

and this way I invoke the user control in my main window (xaml):

```
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding currentChildView}"
                                    Grid.Row="2"
                                    Margin="20"/>
```

this the code in the main principal (cs):

```
        public ICommand cmdControl { get; }
        private ViewModelBase _curretnChildView;

        public ViewModelBase currentChildView
        {
            get { return _curretnChildView; }
            set 
            {
                _curretnChildView = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(currentChildView));
            }
        }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            cmdControl = new ViewModelCommand(ExecuteShowAddUserControl);
        }

        private void ExecuteShowAddUserControl(object obj)
        {
            currentChildView = new usercontrolmodelview();
        }
```

xaml code where the command that shows the user control is linked:

```
                    <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource menuButton}"
                                 Tag="{StaticResource colorClosed}"
                                 Command="{Binding cmdControl}">
                    </RadioButton>
```

as extra data the user control if it is displayed in the main window.

I have tried to change the type of source by datacontext and even so the combobox is not filled

Answer (score 0):

Your usercontrolmodelview should implement INotifyPropertyChanged to tell your view when a property changed and the view needs to refresh that proprety. This is espacially important when dealing with async operations.

A sample implementation could look like this:

```cs
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info) {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
```

I also like to create a ViewModelBase class which implements this interface and make all my viewmodels inherit from it, but this is personal preference.

In the Setter of your public IEnumerable Concepts, you call             NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Concepts));

Please note, that if you collection of concepts might change later, you should use a ObservableCollaction and call the PropertyChangedEvent on the CollectionChanged Event handler.

Hope this helps
~BrainyXS